# Create Group Chat in MS Teams

Tags: curl, error-handling, microsoft-graph-teams

I use MS teams API to create conversation with teams user and send proactive message for starting a chat.

I use this CURL for create a chat - and it's work fine:

```
curl --location 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0e..............................' \
--data '{
  "members": [
    {
      "id": USER_ID
    }
  ],
  "bot": {
    "id": BOT_ID
  },
  "tenantId": TENANT_ID
}'
```

I want one of 2 options:

1. Create a chat group with 2 users
2. Create a one-on-one chat with a different name

option 1:

I tried to execute a CURL like this:

```
curl --location 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0e..............' \
--data '{
      "members": [
    { "id": USER1_ID},
    { "id": USER2_ID}
  ],
    "bot": {
        "id": BOT_ID
    },
        "tenantId": TENANT_ID,
        "isGroup": true

}'
```

But I get an error:

> BadSyntax - Incorrect conversation creation parameters

Option 2:

I haven't seen any way to do this - is it even possible?